# Readme on Github and PyPi

Tags: python, github, pypi

I have my python library on pypi and github. There's only one README file in it which is README.md and it's displayed properly on github. But on pypi it doesn't, it's shown as a plain text. How come and what can I do about it?

Preferably **without** involving a third-party libraries such as Pandoc.

Comment: I don't think you can do it without third-party conversion.  See [this discussion](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi/issue/148/support-markdown-for-readmes).

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [this posting](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html).

To quote the relevant section:

> Every package on PyPI needs to have a file called setup.py at the root of the directory. If your'e using a markdown-formatted read me file you'll also need a setup.cfg file.
>
> setup.cfg
>
> This tells PyPI where your README file is.
>
> > [metadata]
> >
> > description-file = README.md
>
> This is necessary if you're using a markdown readme file. At upload time, you may still get some errors about the lack of a readme — don't worry about it. If you don't have to use a markdown README file, I would recommend using reStructuredText (REST) instead.

Comment: Then I have nothing for you.  You should update your question to include those details.